How to/Can I install inside mount blind brackets on a vinyl window sill?
Ordered some inside mount cellular blinds and the instructions say just to mount them to the top dog the window sill. Problem is, seems like we have vinyl window sills with nothing behind them, as we drilled into them and the screw just shot straight in without resistance. Is there a way to mount anything up or should we have gone for outside mount? Screw was about 1.5 and we were about 10" away from the corner.

Some pics would help.
